# AngularJS preprocess specific $http requests

Tags: angularjs

I'm sending a model to server via $http.post, but, say, empty dates must be deleted, ids must be converted to int, in float values comma must be replaced with dot. These are restrictions of the server-side json api, so I'm looking for a way to modify $http request. Complicated part is that the modification rules depend on a api method name, which itself is a part of request.

The most straightforward way is to declare a modifying function and pass model to that function right before $http.post

```
$scope.method1Adapter = function(model) {
    var data = angular.copy(model);
    // 30 lines of modification code
    return data;
};

$http.post("/api", {method: "method1", "data": $scope.method1Adapter($scope.data)})
```

but I think it's a little bit spaghettysh.

Better way is a factory that gets a method name and returns an adapter callback.

```
coreApp.factory("httpAdapter", function() {
    return {
        get: function (method) {
            if (method == 'method1') {
                return function (model) {
                    var data = angular.copy(model);
                    // modifications
                    return data;
                }
            } else {
                return function (model) {
                    return model;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

so i can add this to $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest callbacks chain

```
coreApp.config(function($httpProvider, httpAdapterProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.unshift(function(post) {
        if (post && post.data && post.data) {
            post.data = httpAdapterProvider.$get().get(post.method)(post.method);
        }
    })
});
```

And still I don't like that, because api for my application has 16 methods, and it would require 5 adapters which is about 100 lines of code hard to maintain.

Any ideas about more clean and neat solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't chain adapters here because, as you said, it would be hard to maintain.

My advice would be to use the $http interceptors (not the responseInterceptors, which are deprecated, but the normal one, see http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http).

Notice in that you have access to the "config" object that has the request url, amongst other interesting properties.

It won't be superneat but at least the problem can be contained in one isolated part of your codebase.